# Why is Python's Logger Returning Errors When There Isn't An Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I think I am not understanding how Python's logging library works. I have a simple function:

```
 def all_caps(_string):

    logging.debug("debug") 
    logging.info("info") 
    logging.warning("warning") 
    logging.error("error")
    logging.critical("critical")

    return _string.upper()
```

From what I understand from tutorials, if I run this function with an input that produces no errors (e.g. `all_caps("hello")`), I should see the output:

```
DEBUG:root:debug
INFO:root:info
```

However, I see the exact opposite:

```
WARNING:root:warning
ERROR:root:error
CRITICAL:root:critical
HELLO
```

Am I crazy? Am I using logging fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Some good info: https://timber.io/blog/the-pythonic-guide-to-logging/#levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each logging function you call from the module will have the root logger send the requested message at the corresponding level, so with the *default configuration*, you should see messages for at least everything *WARN and higher*.

Comment: "by default" should be _emphasized_ or **emphasized**

Comment: I've reworded it hopefully to make it clearer. I could emphasize it too if it's not enough. Thanks!

Comment: The answer was clear enough already. However, I think it is important to highlight the that "WARN and higher" is only by default. However, your answer clarifies the confusion that @Anton I believe had: logging works from a set level _up_ and not _down_.

Comment: Oh! So each call I make sends the requested message, and then these messages are filtered by the `level` parameter?

Comment: That's it, yes. And both loggers and handlers can have level filters, too.

Comment: I agree about defaults. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your default logging level appears to be set to WARNING.  Reset it using `logging.basicConfig` to get the desired results.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> def all_caps(_string):
...     logging.debug("debug")
...     logging.info("info")
...     logging.warning("warning")
...     logging.error("error")
...     logging.critical("critical")
...
...     return _string.upper()
...
>>> all_caps("hello")
DEBUG:root:debug
INFO:root:info
WARNING:root:warning
ERROR:root:error
CRITICAL:root:critical
'HELLO'
```